# Pandas Groupby Apply Function within a Class

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a concern about using `groupby.apply` function within a class. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': [date(2021,6,1), date(2021,6,2), date(2021,6,3), date(2021,6,4), date(2021,6,1), date(2021,6,2), date(2021,6,3), date(2021,6,4)],
                    'ticker':   ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'close':   [5, 4, 2, 3, 10, 12, 11, 12]})


    def expected_calculation(self):
        self.df['weight'] = self.df['close'].values / self.df['close'].sum()
        self.df['pct_change'] = self.df['close'].values.pct_change()


    def job(self):
        self.df = self.df.groupby(['date_time', 'ticker']).apply(self.expected_calculation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testing = Calculator()
    testing.job()
```

I tried to run the above code, but it returns me the error `TypeError: expected_calculation() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. It is necessary to use `groupby` because I want to conduct calculation by each subset (i.e. one data set for a ticker). I realize it is related to the `apply` function but I cannot find the way out.

Could you help me to resolve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use apply,it passes the row values as arguments to the function.So `expected_calculation`function expect row values as a parameter.
Another thing is following the best practices while working with classes.Your `expeted_calculation` function has nothing to do with instances of the class.so it is better to use `staticmethod`.
Try this solution

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': [date(2021,6,1), date(2021,6,2), date(2021,6,3), date(2021,6,4), date(2021,6,1), date(2021,6,2), date(2021,6,3), date(2021,6,4)],
                    'ticker':   ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'close':   [5, 4, 2, 3, 10, 12, 11, 12]})

    @staticmethod
    def expected_calculation(x):
        x['weight'] = x['close'].values / x['close'].sum()
        x['pct_change'] = x['close'].pct_change()
        return x


    def job(self):
        self.df = self.df.groupby(['date_time', 'ticker']).apply(self.expected_calculation)
```